# Include file with module from AngularJS app into RequireJS config file in Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs, phantomjs, karma-runner

As we know, when use RequireJS in the configuration file we must define 'paths' and 'shim'. When writing tests (Karma, Jasmine), we need to create an additional configuration file for RequireJS and re-define the same data.

I try to extract common parts and load them dynamically. In Angular JS application, everything works without problems, but in test i have always error '404'. But let's get to the beginning. Simple example structure:

```
.
|-- newApp
|   |-- app
|   |   `-- app.require.js
|   |-- newApp.require.js
|   `-- index.html
`-- test
    |-- test.karma.js
    `-- test.require.js
```

**index.html** load RequireJS config file

```
<script data-main="newApp.require.js" src="bower_components/requirejs/require.js"></script>
```

**newApp.require.js** init RequireJS

```
require([
    'app/app.require'
], function (appRequire) {
    "use strict";

    require.config({
        baseUrl: 'app',
        paths: appRequire.paths,
        shim: appRequire.shim,
        deps: [
            'NewAppBootstrap'
        ]
    });
});
```

**app.require.js** Module / object with paths and shim

```
define([
    'some/others/components.require'
], function (componentsRequire) {
    "use strict";

    var appRequire = {
        'NewApp': 'app.module',
        'NewAppBootstrap': 'app.bootstrap',
        'NewAppRoute': 'app.routes'
    };

    var vendorRequire = {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$'
        },
        'angular': {
            exports: 'angular'
        }
    };

    return {
        paths: Object.assign(
            appRequire,
            componentsRequire
        ),
        shim: vendorRequire
    };
});
```

Up to this point everything works fine. Now I would like to file **app.require.js** load into **test.require.js**. And the problems begin...

**test.require.js**

```
var TEST_REGEXP = /(spec|test)\.js$/i;
var allTestFiles = [];

Object.keys(window.__karma__.files).forEach(function (file) {
    'use strict';

    if (TEST_REGEXP.test(file)) {
        var normalizedTestModule = file.replace(/^\/base\/|\.js$/g, '');
        allTestFiles.push(normalizedTestModule);
    }
});

require([
    'app/app.require'
], function (appRequire) {
    "use strict";

    require.config({
        baseUrl: '/base/newApp',
        waitSeconds: 200,
        paths: appRequire.paths,
        shim: appRequire.shim,
        deps: allTestFiles,
        callback: window.__karma__.start
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, I still have error:

```
WARN [web-server]: 404: /app/app.require.js
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR: 'There is no timestamp for app/app.require.js!'

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) ERROR
  Error: Script error for "app/app.require"
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror at node_modules/requirejs/require.js:143
```

I tried different paths, but still nothing. Does anyone know how to load this file? Whether it is at all possible load file in this place? I would be grateful for any tips.

Comment: have you tried changing the path to: `../newApp/app/app.require`

Comment: of course, also I tried: app.require, app/app.require, newApp/app/app.require, ../newApp/app/app.require. Even with /base but the error was still the same...

Comment: perhaps the answer here can be of help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20733090/karma-error-there-is-no-timestamp-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time your code hits this `require` call:

```
require([
    'app/app.require'
],
```

There is no RequireJS configuration in effect, and `data-main` is not used, so by default RequireJS takes the directory that contains the HTML page that loads RequireJS as the `baseUrl` (See [the documentation](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl).) Since `index.html` sits at the root, then RequireJS resolves your module name to `/app/app.require.js` and does not find it.

You can work around it by using a full path:

```
require([
    'base/newApp/app/app.require'
],
```

Or if it so happens that other code later is going to try to access this same module as `app/app.require`, then you should have a minimal configuration before your first `require` call:

```
require.config({
  baseUrl: '/base/newApp',
});
```

It is perfectly fine to call `require.config` multiple times. Subsequent calls will override values that are atomic (like `baseUrl`) and marge values that can be merged. (An example of the latter would be `paths`. If the first call sets a `paths` for the module `foo` and a 2nd call sets a `paths` for the module `bar`, then the resulting configuration will have `paths` for both `foo` and `bar`.)